# dynamically filter the content based on current quarter month using search api in drupal

Tags: full-text-search

I created the content type called topic. I have added field called date in topic content. Configured the search_API and created index for search for the title and date. Now i want to display the content of the current quarter month from April to may and also want to change next quarter dynamically in the full text search using views.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please let us know what you've tried using and the problems you've found in order to help you further.

Comment: I created the full text search using view exposed filter in that i want display the content for the current quarter that is dynamically

Comment: what are the ways there to filter content based on current quarter month and year??